# Ways to see all hidden indirect links between an inital link and a final requested link

Tags: google-chrome, url, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools

I have a question regarding URL analysing and would like to hear from your suggestion. Let's say I have an initial link like

https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjss4bPehQTk8U-b_dL-u8qWiuI6Cbwhn7218pwAYYkMiWIWNWSihHAt1yJWix7GXnlOSI9x48XU85Ic4wpF1HJntbx41LBoxW2-9UvLpyrkz6evHsUN7KhUIrW0I1LRl0RLJ7Jjm-fqwCVIkDCoci6Q6786ELSTagmZ5aSK2UyusX9i2Sp8YYMWdN7JcPJSbSsVhSNZkP5OnGOKsL_uVbbh04l6hWEWtCYhb1-76Nw1H&sig=Cg0ArKJSzKBBzahiKXn5EAE&urlfix=1&adurl=https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackclk/N270001.1204588NYT.COM/B20018628.200271182;dc_trk_aid=400259629;dc_trk_cid=90165366;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=

And when I paste that link into my Chrome browser and press enter, it goes to the final link at https://www.celine.com/fr/collections/automne/pret-a-porter/lookbook?utm_campaign=fall2017&utm_source=nyt_fr&utm_medium=display&utm_content=banner_960x270.

Now I want to know what are all the "indirect" link that my browser went through to reach the final link, I wonder if there are any tools or trick to discover that. So basically it can be imagined as I have an initial link called A and this A link leads to the final F link, from A to F my browser has to go through some other B, C, D, E links but these don't show up in browser's display. For some "unhidden" initial links I can see some partial "indirect" link which is already included in the initial link, like the one above with https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackclk can be seen right on it, but many times we don't really see all other links. So are there any ways that we can see all these "indirect" links?

Comment: Simple enable `[x] Preserve log` in network panel of devtools.

Comment: FYI: You mean URLs, not “links”.